# Creating Groups with Dplyr's "group_by" then Using Stringr or Set Operations to Find Differences Between Groups

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I would like to use dplyr and stringr if possible, or at least stay within the Tidyverse to achieve the following:

I need to group the data by CaseWorker and Client and compare "Task" and "Task2" to find all the categories in "Task2" that are not in "Task", along with the associated total time for the "Task2" category.

"Task" can have categories that are not in "Task2", so I'm only interested in finding categories in "Task2" that are not in "Task". It would be great to be able to create new columns to show the specific entries that are in "Task2" and not in "Task", along with the associated "Time" value.

The end result should show four new columns for client Chris, one for "Iron shirt" and one column for the associated "Time" of 45, and a column for "Do homework" and a column for "Time" of 21. There will be two new columns for client Eric, one for "Iron Shirt" and one for the associated time of 12.

```
 CaseWorker<-c("John","John","John","John","John","John","John","John",
"John","Kim","Kim")

  Client<-c("Chris","Chris","Chris","Chris","Chris","Chris","Chris","Chris","Chris","Eric","Eric")

Task<-c("Feed cat","Feed cat","Feed cat","Make dinner","Make dinner","Make dinner","Buy groceries","Buy groceries","Buy groceries","Do homework","Do homework")

Task2<-c("Feed cat","Iron shirt","Iron shirt","Do homework","Do homework","Do homework","Make dinner","Feed cat","Feed cat","Do homework","Iron shirt")

Time<-c(20,34,11,10,5,6,55,30,20,10,12)

Df<-data.frame(CaseWorker,Client,Task,Task2,Time)
```

Comment: It is not clear how your expected output columns should like.  I have the wide format in the solution posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Df %>% 
   group_by(CaseWorker, Client) %>%
   filter(Task2 %in% setdiff(Task2, Task)) %>% 
   group_by(Task2, add=TRUE) %>% 
   summarise(Time = sum(Time)) %>% 
   spread(Task2, Time)
#   CaseWorker Client `Do homework` `Iron shirt`
#*     <fctr> <fctr>         <dbl>        <dbl>
#1       John  Chris            21           45
#2        Kim   Eric            NA           12
```